# Show Space/Desktop Number in Mac OS X Lion in Desktop Top Bar

Tags: macos, desktop, mission-control

In Snow Leopard, it was possible to display the space number in the top right corner of the status bar.

How do you do that in Lion with Mission Control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function was removed by design. Lots of people want this back, so perhaps an add on or secret setting can be discovered later, but for now, the answer is no.

Answer (score -1):

TotalSpaces is a good alternative: http://totalspaces.binaryage.com/

TotalSpaces2 have an icon in menubar, like Spaces in Snow Leopard. More intelligent and more powerful application, as the factory default. You can define a grid of spaces, and you can use your fullscreen apps in a new row… This program now available from $18, but the two weeks long trial period is free. See the intro: http://cdn.binaryage.com/totalspaces2-intro.mp4