# Space number in menubar

Tags: macos, menu-bar, mission-control, spaces

Is there a way to show the space number in the menubar so you can easily tell which desktop you are on in yosemite?

Comment: Let's see whether things improved since Lion (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17982/show-space-desktop-number-in-mac-os-x-lion-in-desktop-top-bar?rq=1)

Comment: I have a different background for each space, letting me see which one is which.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the menubar but you can show the name of the wallpaper on the desktop if that helps:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock desktop-picture-show-debug-text -bool TRUE;killall Dock
```

Source: http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/20/show-the-location-path-of-current-wallpaper-in-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 0):

TotalSpaces is a good alternative:
http://totalspaces.binaryage.com/

TotalSpaces2 have an icon in menubar, like Spaces in Snow Leopard.
More intelligent and more powerful application, as the factory default.
You can define a grid of spaces, and you can use your fullscreen apps in a new row…
This program now available from $18, but the two weeks long trial period is free.
See the intro: http://cdn.binaryage.com/totalspaces2-intro.mp4

Comment: Answers should be more than just a link to some webpage. We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Please don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations..

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will write a lot of words… 
(and, if the site will be dead he can't download the program in the words…) :-)